# Variables didn't transfered in include file

Tags: php, html, variables, include

I already searched for answers here or on Google, but I don't find someone with this problem. (or I'm stupid)

I have a page that creates a variable which gets an array from sql query, then, this page include another page.
But the included one says me that the variable is undefined.
Here's my code :

**/controller/page1.php**

```
include_once("../model/database_connection.php");
include_once("../model/members.php");

$membersList = selectAllMembers();

foreach ($membersList as $key => $member)
{
    $membersList[$key]['pseudo_member'] = htmlspecialchars($member['pseudo_member']);
}

include_once("../view/page1.php");
```

**/view/page1.php**

```
<?php foreach ($membersList as $member)
{ ?>
    <div class="table_row">
        [...]
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: membersList in C:\wamp\www\project\view\page1.php
```

**/model/members.php**

```
function selectAllMembers()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $queryString = 'SELECT * FROM `members`';
    $queryResult = $mysqli->query($queryString);
    $resultArray = false;

    if (!$queryResult)
    {
        echo "selectAllMembers query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli-error;
    }
    else
    {
        $resultArray = $queryResult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is it `selectAllMembers()`? What it's does?

Comment: Show code of `include_once("../model/members.php");`

Comment: So `$memberList` is Null, if the `selectAllMembers()` doesn't return any value

Comment: `selectAllMembers()` must return the content you expect in `$membersList ` (an array, I suppose)

Comment: I edited my post with the model/members.php code.

Comment: It seems look fine. The `page1.php` starts with the code above? Or the code above is - i.e. - inner a function?

Comment: @fusion3k That would result in a different error or no error. A variable holding `null` is still a perfectly *defined* variable.

Comment: `/controller/page1.php` is complete. `/view/page1.php` is just the part with use of my variable `$membersList`.

Comment: Are there any `function` definitions or other things you're not showing us in `page1`?

Comment: «That would result in a different error or no error» It's not a arror, it's a “notice”. If you call undefined variable PHP output a notice. But you have also a warning like “Invalid argument supplied for foreach()”?

Comment: In my view, I have an included file `head.php`, that's all. `head.php`contains only HTML.

@fusion3k Yeah, I have the second error too.

Comment: The problem is in the 'page1.php', I think. Either the call is out of the variable scope, or they are unset before. Try to put a `var_dump($membersList)` at top of 'page1.php'. If the output is fine, repeat this step after 'head.php' inclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am completely dumb!
The problem came from my URL rewritting...
I used my view in my rewrite rule, instead of my controller.

**Before**

```
RewriteRule ^members/list.html$ view/page1.php [L]
```

**After**

```
RewriteRule ^members/list.html$ controller/page1.php [L]
```

But thanks for your comments. :)